# Django allauth - how to send users that just signed up with Google to an intermediate screen where they fill out additional informations

Tags: django, django-allauth

I integrated django-allauth with my Django app but I would like to make a small tweak on the current sign-up flow.

**Problem**
Currently if a user uses google sign-up to sign-up on my app, django-allauth creates an account for them extracting a certain amount of informations from google and then send the user to the home-page.

**Desired behavior**
I would like users who just finished the authentication process through google/allauth,to be sent to an intermediate screen (that they can skip if they really want) where they are asked additional informations (like phone number) so that I can complete their profile.

**Setup**

I have a custom user model where email is the main unique id of a user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    #phone = models.IntegerField() to be properly added, not sure how yet

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

My Settings.py

```
...

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',  # new
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    #'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


...


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
]

SITE_ID = 3
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'myusermodel.adapter.MyAccountAdapter'



# Additional configuration settings
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myusermodel.CustomUser'



SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically I had to build this Mixin that I put in my class based views.

The `dispatch` function is the place to make all the `if` checks i want and send users to an intermediate screen if they profile is not complete or something.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class MyLoginRequiredMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):
    def get_login_url(self):
        return reverse('action:login')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return self.handle_no_permission()
        if not request.user.first_name:
            return redirect('www.google.com')

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```